# write(2) still reports success even though I have closed the socket

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I have encountered a problem where even after my server side close()-ed the socket, the client side still can do a single write(), only the second write() will return SIGPIPE, this causes me to lose data as I do not have application level handshake and solely relying on the return value of write(). Is there a way for me to get SIGPIPE straight away after the server side closed the connection?

Test program follows:

I am expecting the 2nd write to return SIGPIPE, but it returned success, only the 3rd write returns SIGPIPE! Why is this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void log_error(const char *fmt, ...) 
{
 va_list ap;
 char buf[BUFSIZ] = {0};

 va_start(ap, fmt);
 vsnprintf(buf, BUFSIZ, fmt, ap);
 fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", buf);
 va_end(ap);
 return;
}

static int create_inet_socket()
{
    int fd;
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
    int yes = 1;

    if ((fd=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))==-1) {
 log_error("create_inet_socket:socket:%d:%s", errno, strerror(errno));
 return -1;
    }

    if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int))==-1) {
 log_error("create_inet_socket:setsockopt:%d:%s", errno, strerror(errno));
 return -1;
    }

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(9998);
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), '0', 8);

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))==-1) {
 log_error("main:bind:%d:%s", errno, strerror(errno));
 return -1;
    }

    if (listen(fd, 5)==-1) {
 log_error("main:listen:%d:%s", errno, strerror(errno));
 return -1;
    }

    return fd;
}

int myconnect()
{
    int fd;
    char ch[1] = {'a'};
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    fd_set wfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    struct hostent *he;
    ssize_t nwritten;

    if ((fd=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))==-1) {
 log_error("rlog:socket failed:%d:%s", errno, strerror(errno));
 return -1;
    }

    bzero(&sin, sizeof(sin));

    if ((he=gethostbyname("localhost"))==NULL) {
 log_error("rlog:gethostbyname failed:%d:%s", errno, strerror(errno));
 return -1;
    }

    sin.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr*)he->h_addr);
    sin.sin_port = htons(9998);
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if (connect(fd,(struct sockaddr *) &sin,sizeof(sin)) == -1) {
 log_error("connect:%d:%s", errno, strerror(errno));
 return 0;
    }

    nwritten = write(fd, &ch, 1);
    if (nwritten==-1) {
 log_error("write:%d:%s", errno, strerror(errno));
    } else {
 fprintf(stderr, "client : 1. written %ld\n", nwritten);
    }
    sleep(3);
    nwritten = write(fd, &ch, 1);
    if (nwritten==-1) {
 log_error("write:%d:%s", errno, strerror(errno));
    } else {
 fprintf(stderr, "client : 2. written %ld\n", nwritten);
    }
    sleep(3);
    nwritten = write(fd, &ch, 1);
    if (nwritten==-1) {
 log_error("write:%d:%s", errno, strerror(errno));
    } else {
 fprintf(stderr, "client : 3. written %ld\n", nwritten);
    }
    return 0;
}

void run_server()
{
    int fd;
    int newfd;
    char c[1];
    ssize_t nread;
    int status;
    fprintf(stderr, "server : Running\n");
    fd = create_inet_socket();
    if (fd==-1) {
 perror("create_inet_socket");
    }

    newfd = accept(fd, NULL, NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "server : accepted newfd %d\n", newfd);

    nread = read(newfd, &c, 1);
    if (nread==-1) {
 log_error("read:%d:%s", errno, strerror(errno));
    } else {
 fprintf(stderr, "read returned %ld, closing socket\n", nread);
    }
    shutdown(newfd, SHUT_RDWR);
    close(newfd);
    wait(&status);
    fprintf(stderr, "server : exit\n");
}

void run_client()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "client : running\n");
    myconnect();
    fprintf(stderr, "client : exit\n");
    _exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    int pid = fork();
    switch (pid) {
    case 0:
 run_client();
 break;
    case -1:
 perror("fork");
 break;
    default:
 run_server();
 break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot rely just on the return value of `write(2)` - this is a big race condition between two ends of the connection (kernel caches the data you give to system calls, packets take time to cross the wire, etc.) and thus introduces a possibility of data loss in case of the transport-level connection tear-down. If you need reliability, design your application-level protocol so that receiving side acknowledges all data.

There used to be a nice article about something like this - [The ultimate SO_LINGER page or why is my TCP not reliable](http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable), but it seems to be down at the moment. Google that title, it might be mirrored somewhere.

Comment: After 30 minutes of searching for the cache of the page, finally found it at 
http://ds9a.nl/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable.txt, this is the best I got, hope its the same as the original version.